# C# Рефакторинг метода через Linq

Tags: c#, linq, рефакторинг

Имеется метод:

```
public static List<string> ConvertToListString<T>(T data)
    {
        List<string> list = new List<string>();
        foreach (var item in data.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            list.Add(item.GetValue(data).ToString());
        }

        return list;
    }
```

Он конвертит любой тип данных, который ему прилетит в параметре.
Хотелось бы написать это через Linq, хотелось бы расширить свои навыки, буду признателен за любую помощь.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Конечно, вот Linq

```cs
public static List<string> ConvertToListString<T>(T data)
    => data.GetType()
           .GetProperties()
           .Select(p => p.GetValue(data).ToString())
           .ToList();
```

Comment: Спасибо вам за помощь!